# File not uploading to directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using a form for uploading an image to my *img* folder. The error code of the photo array is 0, that means that there isn't any error and the file was uploaded successfully, but it wasn't... This is the code I have:

**This is the HTML:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <label>Thumbnail:</label>
    <input name="thumbnail" type="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**This is the *upload.php* file:**

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'img/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['thumbnail']['name']);
echo $uploadfile;

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

I've put a `print_r($_FILES)` because I want to see the array... This is what I get after uploading the picture:

```
Array
(
    [thumbnail] => Array
        (
            [name] => Stack.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpEo6Gu5
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 482278
        )

)
```

And, if you look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), you can see that error 0 corresponds to:

> There is no error, the file uploaded with success.

But I don't have any files in my folder... This is the tree-view of the folders:

```
|test
|||img (folder)
|||||somephoto.png
|||||otherphoto.png
|||upload.php
```

But there isn't any photo in there because I can't upload them... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: I know there are a lot of security risks here, but I'm only testing in my local machine, later, if it works, I'll add all the security-related code.

Comment: turn on `display_error` in your `PHP.ini`, or just use [Image Uploader](https://github.com/simon-eQ/BulletProof) It is safe, because I made it :)

Comment: I think it is enabled... Isn't it? [This is what I have](http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/0e443c5dc22a9b1cff86664d02ecbf0a.png). And if I cannot find a solution I'll use your code! Thanks!!

Comment: [Move Uploaded File](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Check Havenards file. But if that is the way you intend to upload files, then you server is at a HUGE risk of getting hacked even by noobs

Comment: There is nothing preventing someone from uploading a `.php` in this. I suggest you make an array of acceptable file extensions and check against it before saving the file.

Comment: @Havenard yes, of course... This was only for testing. I'll add later the exceptions and all the security things but I only wanted to try if the uploading-method was working!

Comment: @simON the same as I said in the comment before!

Comment: @peregraum Good. If you are uploading only images, then use `exif_imagetype` function. It is the best and most reliable.

Comment: @simON Oh thanks for the feedback! So using a `if (exif_imagetype($_FILE['thumbnail']) != IMAGETYPE_PNG)` for detecting if the image is not a PNG image would be right? (I've taken the info from [the php page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php))

Comment: @peregraum Yes. You can [check here](https://github.com/simon-eQ/BulletProof/blob/master/ImageUploader/BulletProof.php#L175-L184) to see more, that way you don't have to compare the output with each construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is uploaded to a temporary folder, as `print_r($_FILES)` showed, the *actual* file is `/tmp/phpEo6Gu5`.

You have to use `move_uploaded_file()` to move this file to its final destination. Example:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILE['thumbnail']['tmp_name'], 'img/final_name.png');
```

Do not trust `$_FILE['thumbnail']['name']` or `$_FILE['thumbnail']['type']` as safe and valid, because this comes from client-side and can be twisted by an ill-intentioned user to exploit security issues in your site.

In addition, make sure the user account your script runs with has permission to write to the final directory. Easy way to solve that would be running `chmod 777 img` in your shell (gives full read+write+execute permission to everyone in folder `img`).

Comment: Actually, this is what I have... But it doesn't work :/

Comment: also make sure that your img folder is writable and owner is www-data `chown www-data. img` and `chmod +x img` if you are using linux

Comment: um...www-data is dependent on the unix distro  and apache configuration. PHP is not always running as www-data.

Comment: @peregraum First make sure if everything is up to what you are told here, then make sure if image upload from the same folder is working, because this could be the known issue of `open_basedir` and directory problems.

Comment: @simON Yes, yes, sorry I was testing... The problem was that the folder didn't have the correct permissions. I did a `chmod 777 img` and now I can upload them perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the file from the Temporary directory to your current directory?

PHP uploads to the tmp folder on your server. You will need to use the move_uploaded_file function to get this to another directory:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILE['thumbnail']['tmp_name'], 'img/image.png');
```

[Move Uploaded File](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)